# Eligibility criteria for a model when using it with vertex ai studio GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to use stream with automl model so I've tried to import custom automl model in vertex studio but it shows "0 eligible models in this project ()" (Vertex AI Vision -> Studio -> Import from Vertex AI).[vertex studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlZcN.png)

I have models in the vertex AI model registry it shows two models but I couldn't import it via vertex studio.
[model registry screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekgyt.png)

is there any eligibility criteria for importing automl model using vertex studio? please help me on this.

Is there any other way where I can use automl model for streaming data (image or video classification)?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are facing is expected.

For now, for AutoML models, only object detection models are supported -- that's why you can't see the others available at the same region (us-central-1).

Also, it worths mentioning that if you are going to train an AutoML object detection model to be used with Vertex Vision, you can select one option at the training screen, as described [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision-ai/docs/build-app#train-vertex-automl-model)

Comment: sure. let me try to add object detection model. Thanks